# Alarm only triggers when I'm in the Activity that set it

Tags: android, android-activity, alarm

I'm creating an alarm in my app from the `ItemEdit Activity`.  Its where one can edit/view their note/todo item, they can also set a reminder/alarm for the item there.  I set the alarm with the following code:

```
private void createAlarm() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderReceiver.class);
     intent.putExtra("reminder_message", "Reminder Received!");
     intent.putExtra("item_id", mRowId);
     PendingIntent sender = 
         PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                 getApplicationContext(), 
                 ALARM_ID, 
                 intent, 
                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

     // Get the AlarmManager service
     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     // Set alarm to the time given by the user.
     am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mReminderCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
}
```

And here is the Receiver

```
    public class ReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MyApp";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            String message = bundle.getString("reminder_message");
            Log.v(TAG, message);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "OH SNAP!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Edit: Also I have the following in my manifest:

`<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="ReminderReceiver"></receiver>`

If I stay in the `Activity` where I set the alarm it is received fine.  If I hit the back button to return to my `ListActivity` where all the items are listed or leave the app entirely the alarm never triggers.  Have I done something wrong in setting up my alarm that it only triggers from the Activity that set it?

Thanks.

Comment: I was considering that.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding how the flow of an Alarm works, but I figured the `AlarmManager` was OS wide and would fire regardless of what `Activity` was currently active.  I could be wrong in this assumption though.

Comment: @Jonathon.  You were correct I got it working with a `Service`  could you create an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: added it -- you could enter an answer and select your own since I really didn't help you that much :)

Comment: Nah, you got me on the right track you deserve it! cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead of an `Activity` for a long-living process that doesn't interact with the user (like an alarm clock).